# real time update include_values is not supported

Tags: facebook-graph-api, subscriptions, real-time-updates

I wanted to update the "callback_url" (https://graph.facebook.com/subscriptions) but the problem is that I can not add the "include_values" and it is a very big problem because my entire program works with

{
"error": {
"message": "(#100) include_values is not supported",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 100
}
}

**example facebook callback with "include_values"**

{"object":"user","entry":[{"id":"44368442315","time":1346984937,"changes":[{"field":"feed","value":{"item":"like","verb":"add","parent_id":"44368442315_10151242317912316","sender_id":1422826573,"created_time":1346984937}}]}]}

**example facebook callback not "include_values"**

{"object":"user","entry":[{"id":"329196660309","time":1347472236,"changed_fields":["feed"]},{"id":"44368442315","time":1347472238,"changed_fields":["feed"]}]}

Comment: I don't see that parameter in the documentation - what does it do?

Comment: Well, obviously it doesn’t :-P I’d suggest you read the official docs on how real-time updates work and are to be set up, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/

Comment: I read the doc is a parameter that was not in the doc but we found it a while ago and that worked very well http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7367948/how-to-subscribe-to-real-time-updates-for-a-facebook-pages-wall (this parameter can have whether it is a "like add" "add comment" ...)
if an employee of facebook is here

Comment: That this parameter might have worked at some point in the past, does not mean it has to work now. There is no mention of it in the docs, and the error message you are getting is pretty clear. And also the docs for Real-Time Updates clearly state, “Note that [the callback] does not include the actual data values (either from before or after the update).”

Comment: I have read the doc but it worked very well there are less than 3 weeks, even with complete values ​​for 2 to 3 weeks for periods of a few days. For the parameter "inlude_values​​" if we go more than a boolean it returns a error: this parameter must be a boolean, so this parameter is

Answer (score 3):

This property is unsupported, and correctly undocumented. The required pattern is to query back to get the updated field, clearly marked in the ping.

And indeed, in some scenarios it is optimal to do this: for example batching up a query to get the final state for all the changes of a fast-moving property that have been made over a period of time.

Note that you can now use [field expansion](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/field_expansion/) to laser-focus your resulting query and any nested connections required.

Comment: In an ideal world it would work over time, but there are number of problems such as the fact that the posts will no longer be updated (updated_time) when there are more than 30 or 40 comments, so it is difficult for return of the proofing new comments, another problem is that we do not know what has been deleted, as the feed of a page can not tell the difference between a new comment or like so it multiplies the number of request for nothing or makes the system totally unusable, the parameter inludes_value rule all these problems.

Comment: note: 3 weeks ago values ​​appeared (as before there was the description without ids - eg "add comment feed" "add feed like"), so the system was ideal because we could maintain a feed with minimal requests.

Comment: What is the app (ID or name) that was using this successfully in the past?

Comment: thank you for helping me, that my application called "What's on walls" and id is 183637701702463 (I still logs this period with all the info inside)

Comment: ok I was in the right for a while and I knew more than some
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#realtime