# Real time updates notification on feed post removal

Tags: facebook, real-time, updates, feed

Here the scenario.
I have an app the requests each new user read_stream and publish_actions permissions.
The app is subscribed to user->feed real time updates.

The app publishes a post on the user_fuid/feed everytime the user performs a specific action.

I need the real time updates system to post to my callback whenever the user deletes (or, better, deletes or hides) one of the posts published by my app.

Is that possible?
If so, is that the optimal solution or can I do it better (like with less permissions, higher performances, etc.)?

So far, I've received notifications upon posting and liking. But I quite have the feeling that the real time updates system reacts on an paradigm of accretion of the graph but do not notifies removals. Am I right?

Comment: hi i have the same problem look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12392381/real-time-update-include-values-is-not-supported

Comment: It seems that this "include_values" cannot be relied for professional products, am I right?